# Azure Data Studio - way to change default connection type for Azure SQL Databases?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-data-studio

I just recently started to use Azure Data Studio to replace SSMS and VS Code.  So far it is working great. I do have one "issue" I was wondering if anyone else encounters. I run the application with my Azure AD Admin. Under Connections I see all of my subscriptions and the underlying databases:

[image: Azure SQL Connections]

When I try to expand a server, I get an error that it is trying to connect with a SQL account:

[image: Connection Error]

It then brings up the connection details where it is set to use SQL Authentication:

[image: Default connection settings]

[image: Changed Auth type]

If I change the Authentication type to Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA support, and click connect it does without issue.

My question is, is there a way to change what the server connection uses as a default so I don't have to try to expand, fail, change auth type, and then connect?  It is nice not having to manually create all of the connections to all of our subscriptions and sql servers and just have them load there and open them.

Comment: We can't change the default authentication type, Data Studio doesn't provide such settings for us. Even we have manually add the connection with AD authentication, when we click the server in Azure, it needs login again and change to SQL login.

Comment: I have made a feature request to the Azure Data Studio team [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/13851).  Please add a comment of upvote it for attention.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I searched all the settings of Azure data studio, but did not find the option to change the default authentication type of login Azure SQL.

User and workspace setttings of Azure data studio, you can refrence this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/settings?view=sql-server-ver15).

You can click the **power plug icon** in the right and then choose Authentication type to login to the server.

[image]

Comment: That works, but when you try to expand the database to see object in it, it fails with the same error and you have to log in again.  Then if you right click on a table and select top 1000, same thing.  It would be great to just default to azure ad so I don't have to set up the connections or reconnect over and over manually changing that setting.